# Sum of Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum two ranges, but I can't do it

I've tried both ways

```
Set Total = Application.Sum(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("Range")) 

as well as

Set Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("Range"))
```

Nothing really works, tried also make variable as the range and then Application/WorksheetFunction.sum(Variable) but also does not work

Any suggestions? I have to do that as the SUM in VBA, not as "=SUM()"

Comment: you do not `Set` a number.  Remove that word.

Comment: `Set` is only for objects, a sum is a simple numerical value not an object, therefore it is without `Set`.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, at least it goes further, however it keeps getting error "object required". Error 424. Any thoughts?

Comment: @rainbowthug In which line of code? Please see [mcve]. Please [edit] your quesiton and give the information needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You can [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/let-statement) it be, but since it's optional I don't think anybody use it.